# Replace a string in an attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to replace a string in an attribute with jQuery.

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="text" class="wu-autocomplete ui-autocomplete-input" value="Hongkong, China" autocomplete="off">
```

So basically, the value "Hongkong, China" needs to be replaced with a new string called "sample".

What's the most practical way to get this done with a jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: The most practical way is to learn jQuery basics. According to your HTML: `$('.wu-autocomplete.ui-autocomplete-input').val("sample");`

Comment: Yes, as Regent said, it's ***well worth*** your time to read through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes two hours, tops, and it repays you that time almost immediately. Tutorials are also useful.

Comment: I added this jquery, but the value remains.

Answer (score 1):

To change the value of an input-field you can simply use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)-function of jQuery:

```
$('input[type=text]').val('sample');
```

If you want to change the attribute visibly in the hmtl-markup you can use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)-function:

```
$('input[type=text]').attr('value', 'sample');
```

Of course you can use every other selector fitting your needs.

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4o1hus17/)**

Answer (score 0):

first, give this element an ID, for example, `txtInput`:

```
<input id="txtInput" type="text" class="wu-autocomplete ui-autocomplete-input" value="Hongkong, China" autocomplete="off">
```

then, just do:

```
$('#txtInput').val('NEW VALUE!');
```

**note**: in order to change ALL text input values, use:

```
$('input[type="text"]').val('NEW VALUE!');
```

hope that helps.

Comment: why do i need to give it an id?

Comment: if you want to modify a SINGLE text input, you must refer to it specifically, ID, is one of the methods to do so. BUT, if you want to modify ALL text inputs at once, you don't need an ID (see my note in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use simple jQuery here. Because this is an input, you can use a `val()` method, like so:

```
var input = $('.ui-autocomplete-input');
input.val('sample');
```

To find your field you can use:

```
 var input = $('input[type=text]') // will search by type
```

or

```
 var input = $('.ui-autocomplete-input') // will search by class name
```

But the best solution would be to add an id to your input, and select element by id:

```
var input = $('#inputId')
```